# Meteor: Must pass options.email uncaught error

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, forgot-password, password-recovery

I'm working on a custom login system with Meteor and I have run into the following error when using the `Accounts.forgotPassword()` function:  `Uncaught Error: Must pass options.email`

This is what I have on the relative html side:

```
<form id="recovery-form" action="action" class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Recover Password</h4>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input id ="recoveryEmail" type="text" name="recoveryEmail">
    <input id="sendResetInstructionbtn" class="btn btn-default loginbtn" type="submit" value="Send Reset Instructions">
</form>
```

And this is the submit function:

```
'submit #recovery-form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var validated = true;
        email = trimInput(template.find('#recoveryEmail').value);

    if(email === "") {
        alert("Email is empty");
        console.log("Email is empty");
    }

    if (validated) {
        Session.set('loading', true);
        Accounts.forgotPassword({email: email}, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                alert("Password Reset Failed");
                console.log("Password Reset Failed" + err);
            } else {
                alert("Email sent");
                console.log("Email sent, check email");
            }
            Session.set('loading', false);
        });
    }
    return false; // Stops page from reloading
}
```

It runs fine right up until the Accounts.forgotPassword function

Please assist, I'm kinda a Meteor noob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this code, it works for me :

```
var options = {};
options.email = email;
Accounts.forgotPassword(options, function(error){  
  if (error) { 
    console.log(error);
  }else{
    alert('Check your mailbox!');
  } 
});
```